# Declaring SQLite Variables

Tags: sql, variables, stored-procedures, sqlite

Is there a way to declare variables in SQLite. I'm using a combination of C# and Objective C, both of which support the addition of parameters but how do I go about declaring variables through the console or via a DBMS ([Database.NET](http://fishcodelib.com/database.htm)). The usual syntax of `DECLARE @age INT = 3` doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at this one: [Declare variable in sqlite and use it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7739444/declare-variable-in-sqlite-and-use-it) :

Try using Binding Values. You cannot use variables as you do in T-SQL but you can use "parameters". I hope the following link is usefull.Binding Values

Answer (score 3):

sqlite alone doesn't support stored procs.  Best way to do what you want to do is parameterize a SQL query in your code.

Answer (score -3):

The following additional commands are supported in Database .NET:

1. Binding SQL variables (SELECT statements only):
   **@varname**, **:varname**, **?varname** 
   e.g.
   SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE COL1=**@varname**
2. Self-defined SQL variables:
   (Specifying a fixed variable) **:setvar  "value"** 
   (Specifying a dynamic variable) **:setvar**  
   (Using a variable) **$(varname)** 
   e.g. 
   **:setvar FixedVar "%e%" 

   :setvar DynamicVar** 
   SELECT * FROM [Categories] WHERE [CategoryName] LIKE '**$(FixedVar)**' AND [CategoryID]=**$(DynamicVar)**