# SQLITE Case Expression with variable to avoid double evaluation of expression

Tags: sql, database, sqlite

Hi I have a query where a expression is gonna be evaluated in most cases twice. I only want it evaluated once. I want to assign

```
CAST(ROUND(VOLUME - ((CAPACITY*1.0)/TIMEFRAME)*(STRFTIME('%s','now') - UPDATED_TIMESTAMP)) AS INT)
```

to a variable, so it doesn't get evaluated twice.  How can I do this in one sql query?

```
SELECT CASE
           WHEN CAST(ROUND(VOLUME - ((CAPACITY*1.0)/TIMEFRAME)*(STRFTIME('%s','now') - UPDATED_TIMESTAMP)) AS INT) > 0 THEN CAST(ROUND(VOLUME - ((CAPACITY*1.0)/TIMEFRAME)*(STRFTIME('%s','now') - UPDATED_TIMESTAMP)) AS INT)
           ELSE 0
       END
FROM BUCKETS;
```

Comment: What do you mean when you say it's going to be evaluated twice?  Sample data and desired results would be helpful.

Comment: if CAST(ROUND(VOLUME - ((CAPACITY*1.0)/TIMEFRAME)*(STRFTIME('%s','now') - UPDATED_TIMESTAMP)) AS INT) > 0  then the same expression will be evaluated and returned as as result.  The expression always returns integers

Comment: If an expression occurs multiple times in the sames statement it IS only evaluated once.

Comment: @DaleM if that is an answer could you please post it as an answer instead of a comment.

Comment: can you do this? [Declare variable in sqlite and use it](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7739444/declare-variable-in-sqlite-and-use-it)

Comment: I want to do it in one sql query.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can evaluate expression in subquery and then use it's name (`expr`) in query:

```
SELECT CASE
           WHEN expr > 0 THEN expr
           ELSE 0
       END
FROM (
  SELECT
    -- add BUCKETS.*, here if you need other BUCKETS fields return to query
    CAST(ROUND(VOLUME - ((CAPACITY*1.0)/TIMEFRAME)*(STRFTIME('%s','now') - UPDATED_TIMESTAMP)) AS INT) AS expr 
  FROM BUCKETS
) b
```

Answer (score 4):

+1 to the answer from @Rimas.

For what it's worth, here's a similar solution using a [Common Table Expression](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_with.html).

```
WITH buckets_enhanced AS (
  SELECT CAST(ROUND(VOLUME - ((CAPACITY*1.0)/TIMEFRAME)*(STRFTIME('%s','now') - UPDATED_TIMESTAMP)) AS INT) AS expr 
  FROM BUCKETS
)
SELECT CASE WHEN expr > 0 THEN expr ELSE 0 END 
FROM buckets_enhanced;
```

It's useful to learn to use CTE's because they're more powerful than simply a derived-table subquery.
For example, you can use the CTE multiple times in the outer query, as in a self-join.