# how to create variable in query sqlite

Tags: sqlite, variables

I want to use variable in my query for sqlite but I don't know how do it?

my query is it :

```
/*I want to declare my variable in here and use this variable query*/

/*declare vaiable*/SELECT direct_station.iddirect_station,station.name,line.color FROM direct_station JOIN
direction ON direction.iddirection = direct_station.iddirection JOIN
station ON station.idstation = direction.laststation JOIN line ON line.idline = direction.line WHERE direct_station.idstation = /*put variable*/
```

**Explain :**

my friends I want execute one query but this query have two part :

first part I want to get several value like this `{178,180,200,300}`. I got this from this query :

```
SELECT direct_station.iddirect_station FROM direct_station WHERE direct_station.idstation = 98
```

and second part I want to use any these values to this query by one variable :

```
SELECT * FROM stations_view WHERE iddirection = %d
```

now I want to get any value from second query that joined to first query.

Comment: Appears to be a similar question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7739444/declare-variable-in-sqlite-and-use-it

Comment: @f01 this not working for me

Comment: What is the purpose of the variable? Are you trying to write a recursive query?

Comment: @CL. I don't know about recursive query but I want one query like for loop that include from two part (first part get 4 value for example 1,2,3,4 and second part take this values tandem) please guide me about it....

Comment: I think maybe I want to write recursive query. do you explain about that?

Comment: Edit the question to show example data and the desired result.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the solution could be to create a Table for your variable where you are going to store the variable's value and from where you can retrieve the value when needed.

```
INSERT INTO VariableTable (Variable) VALUES ('x');

SELECT * FROM TableName WHERE ColumnName = (SELECT Variable FROM VariableTable);
```

Comment: my friend I want to create and use variable in one query.

Comment: May be I didn't get the point of your question. Which language are you going to use to execute your query?

Comment: objective c my friend

Comment: Why don't you do all the query building job on the application side leaving to sqlite only the query execution job?