# Define constant in SQLite C/C++ API

Tags: c++, c, sqlite, api

Does the SQLite C/C++ API support a way to define a constant for usage in queries? Something like this:

```
SELECT user_defined_function(USER_DEFINED_CONSTANT)
```

where `USER_DEFINED_CONSTANT` evaluates to some specified value.

Comment: Have you looked at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7739444/declare-variable-in-sqlite-and-use-it

Comment: Yes.  I was asking about the C/C++ API...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a user-defined function that always returns the same value.  Alternatively, since you're talking about the C API, you could consider using a variable or a constant at the C level to help create the text of your prepared statements (containing a *bona fide* SQL literal).

As far as I know or can determine, however, you cannot define a symbol that SQLite will automatically transform to a constant.