# Is it possible to assign variable values inside SQLite select statements?

Tags: sql, sqlite, assignment-operator

MySQL has the := operator, which can be used inside a SELECT statement (i.e SELECT @var := 1), but I couldn't find a similar operator for SQLite.

Is it even possible to assign a value in such way? I found this answer: [Declare variable in sqlite and use it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7739444/declare-variable-in-sqlite-and-use-it) but it requires creating a temporary table beforehand.

Thanks!

Comment: There is no such thing. The link you gave has the answers to your question.

Comment: What is the actual problem you're trying to solve?