# IF option in sqlite returning syntax error

Tags: database, sqlite, exists, not-exists

I need a way to run some sql commands ONLY IF a record doesn't already exist in my db.
I have the following .sql file so far:

```
PRAGMA foreign_keys=OFF;    
BEGIN TRANSACTION;

IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM widgets WHERE name="123")
BEGIN
ALTER TABLE table2 ADD COLUMN mynewcolumn VARCHAR(255);    
INSERT INTO table2 ("abc", "def")
END
COMMIT;
```

But this fails with a syntax error.
I know that IF does exist in sqlite but it seems it's only a part of the CREATE statement.
[Declare variable in sqlite and use it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7739444/declare-variable-in-sqlite-and-use-it)

I'm wondering if you can suggest a different way I can accomplish the task above?

Comment: `CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS` is special syntax for `CREATE TABLE`, not a general thing.

Comment: @Schwern yeah i guess you just added this comment as I was updating my entire question.

Comment: how do i contest the "duplicate" comment?  This is not the same question

Comment: Address a comment to @CL explaining why it isn't a duplicate. But it is, the first answer states "*SQLite has almost no control logic; as an embedded database, it is designed to be used together with a 'real' programming language.*" You can't do what you're asking in pure SQLite, even with `CASE`.

Comment: @Schwern ok.  yeah, i guess that makes sense.