# SQlite SELECT statement alias

Tags: sql, sqlite

Is there some kind of `WITH` expression in SQlite?

For example I'm trying to do (not working)

```
SELECT s.name AS 'service',
(SELECT value FROM payments WHERE (serviceId = s.id) AND (managerId = $managerId)) AS 'payment',
COUNT(s.name) AS 'amount',
('payment' * 'amount') AS summary         //that is the point I want to optimise
FROM tickets t
JOIN services_to_tickets st ON t.id = st.ticketId
JOIN services s ON st.serviceId = s.id
JOIN medics m ON t.medicId = m.id
JOIN managers mg ON mg.id = m.managerId
WHERE mg.id = $managerId
GROUP BY service
```

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7739444/declare-variable-in-sqlite-and-use-it

Comment: @JacobH maybe but it makes query much more complicated. Any simpler suggestions?