# Can We use Select Into or somethng similar in SQLITE Triggers?

Tags: sqlite, triggers

with SQLITE I have 2 tables  Employee (id,name,phone,taskname) and Tasks (id, name,date,Employee_id)

I want to add a trigger on After update of a row to get the taskname from the tasks table where employe_id is the same. I think that this will need to use SELECT INTO NEW.taskname but I can't seem to get it right. I tried.

```
CREATE TRIGGER "gettaskname"
AFTER UPDATE
ON "Employee"
BEGIN
SELECT Tasks.name FROM Tasks INTO NEW.task_name WHERE NEW.id = Tasks.Employee_id;
END;
```

I am getting a syntax error

Comment: Your double quotes aren't balanced.

Comment: And what is `SELECT ... INTO ...`? That's not valid syntax. See https://www.sqlite.org/lang_select.html

Comment: Hi  @Shawn thanks for your reply. I updated the post it is not a quote problem, yes doesn't work I need something similar but with SQLite Any idea?

Comment: *to get the taskname* and do what with that taskname?

Comment: Hi @forpas this is a simplified example of a problem I am facing. my current project is too complex to post it involves a couple tables and some VCL component with very special restriction in front end. Basically I love embedding data (business) logic on backend via triggers but it is tricky with Sqlite.

Comment: You need to explicitly create the table.  Then use an [INSERT... SELECT](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_insert.html) statement.  There are some variations that might be useful like UPSERTS.  It is worth familiarizing yourself with the overall [syntax specifics in sqlite](https://www.sqlite.org/lang.html).

Comment: @C Perkins Thanks for the link I will check up the doc.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you very much for your awesome comments. I found this thread [creating variable inside trigger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7739444/declare-variable-in-sqlite-and-use-it/14574227#14574227) but it didn't work for me and i got sytax errors for using PRAGMA and CREATE TEMP TABLE .

This worked for me:

```
CREATE TRIGGER "gettaskname"
AFTER UPDATE
ON "Employee"
BEGIN
UPDATE Employee SET task_name = (SELECT Tasks.name FROM Tasks WHERE NEW.id = Tasks.Employee_id) WHERE id = NEW.id;
END;
```

Comment: *no body did answer* because you did not explain what you want to do. You posted code implying that you want to **insert** rows in the table but what you actually wanted was to **update** the rows of the table.