# How to automatically insert an auto increment id from one table to another in SQLite?

Tags: sql, database, sqlite

I have the following tables in my db (it's not complete here, but I think that's possible to understand the idea).

| Articles |
| --- |
| id |
| title |

| Author |
| --- |
| id |
| name |

| Articles_Author |
| --- |
| idArticle |
| idAuthor |

I need to insert the articles and authors autoincremented id's in the table 'Articles_Author', in the same row.

When I use `last_insert_rowid()`, it adds in a different row.

Can someone help me?!

Comment: Is the table declared `WITHOUT ROWID`? And are you calling the function immediately after the insert?

Comment: No, it's not... Yep, I'm calling right after the insert, but after the `last_insert_rowid()` is created two rows, for each table (Articles and Author) and not one row in different columns. There's another way of doing it?

Comment: Well you can't use that function for two previous inserts, it will only give the most recent insert on any table. SQLite doesn't support variables, so you need to either save the first insert's ID in a temporary table, or bring it back to the client and pass it through again as a parameter

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Declare variable in SQLite and use it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7739444/declare-variable-in-sqlite-and-use-it)

Comment: Oh, I see.. It definitely helped! I ended up making a temporary table and managing the Id's like you said. Thanks!