# How to declare local variable in DuckDB

Tags: duckdb

In SQL Server, I can declare a [local variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/declare-local-variable-transact-sql) and use it like so:

```
DECLARE @x Int = 7
SELECT @x * 2;
```

Result: 14

How can I declare a **local** variable and use it in my DuckDB SQL script?

Note: this is not the same as SQL *parameters*.

Comment: Maybe copy from workarounds for SQLite: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7739444/declare-variable-in-sqlite-and-use-it

Answer (score 2):

The `DECLARE` keyword is not supported in DuckDB (and many other SQL systems).

You can use macros to define constants:

```
CREATE TEMP MACRO x() AS (SELECT 7);
```

Then, you can use them as follows:

```
SELECT x();
```

(Thanks for the suggestion in @curiouscheese's comment.)

Alternatively, you may create a [temporary table](https://duckdb.org/docs/sql/statements/create_table#temporary-tables) with a single value:

```
CREATE TEMP TABLE x AS SELECT 7::INT AS val;
```

Then, use it as a [scalar subquery](https://duckdb.org/docs/sql/expressions/subqueries#scalar-subquery):

```
SELECT (SELECT val FROM x);
```

DuckDB is good at optimizing subqueries (both scalar and other types), so this this approach should incur no performance penalty.

Comment: Is it possible to use `CREATE TEMPORARY FUNCTION` in duck db?

Comment: @curiouscheese: you can use `CREATE TEMPORARY MACRO`, see https://duckdb.org/docs/sql/statements/create_macro