# How to use variable in SQLite?

Tags: sqlite

How can I use a variable in an SQLite query?

```
select tom from test; #tom is a field in my database,it is ok
```

How can I express the meaning?

```
name="tom"  
select  name from test;
```

Comment: `select tom from test` looks awfully suspicious...  Do you mean `SELECT  <say...> Name, Address, City FROM test WHERE Name = 'Tom'` ?

Comment: Not enough information / Depends upon language/binding / SQLite itself *does not* support a declarative language as found in other SQL dialects like PL/SQL, PL/pgSQL or TSQL - see also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7739444/declare-variable-in-sqlite-and-use-it , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5619145/sqlite-variables depending upon real issue.

Comment: From which language are you accessing SQLite?